# Possible SQL Injection with redirect to webpage if injected query is correct

Tags: sql, sql-injection, sqlmap

Under the authorization of my friend, I am testing his website against potential vulnerabilities.

I was trying to find if I was able to inject a SQL query into a POST request parameter `hi' or 1=1 --`:

```
query=hi'%20or%201%3d1%20--
```

I found that the document prints out:

```
<div class="error">index job,query: syntax error, unexpected '-' near '-'</div>
```

while with `' or 0=0 --` I get:

```
<div class="error">index job,query: syntax error, unexpected '|' near ' | 0=0) --'</div>
```

does this mean that it's vulnerable to SQL Injection? If yes, how can I make it print server system data (like information, etc.)? By the way, if the string is correct it gets redirected to another webpage (I think that's why SQLMap tells me the parameter is not SQL-injectable).

**EDIT:** I can see the query works just if the URL gets redirected, but I won't see the query output. If the URL doesn't get redirected, I can see these SQL query errors. I'm trying to see how to get the output and do something more useful to attack the website, or even make it detectable from `sqlmap`.

The current command I'm using is `sqlmap -r thework.txt -p query --dbs`. `thework.txt` contains the full valid `POST` request.

Answer (score 0):

Wish I had 50 reps so I could put this in comments. But yes the site is most likely vulnerable. To be sure ask your friend to allow you to run an initial exploit.

sqlmap.py -u < Target Address> --dbs

If you successfully pull up the data base you have found the vulnerability or at least have confirmed there is a vulnerability.

Comment: SQLMap doesn't detect the vulnerability.

Comment: This is the command I use `sqlmap -r thework -p query --dbs` `thework` contains the full valid POST request.

Comment: Thank you JavaScripter I did need to know the command you just posted. Correct the command I used does not show the vulnerability but if error message is the result of a vulnerability you normally can pull up the database. If not actually vulnerable you do not.

Comment: Ok, thanks, basically you're saying me that a simple error like on OP implies it's SQLi vulnerable. Now I'm sure it is. Look at my edit and see if you can answer that

Comment: I normally do not follow redirects myself.  Sorry I am not able to actually answer your question on redirects but the original (Home) source I would say is vulnerable from what you have written so far.

Answer (score 0):

SQL injection isn't only about malicious attacks that read data or change data on your site.

The majority of SQL injections are simply errors like the one you saw. They might not even be malicious. What if you have an SQL injection vulnerability that simply causes an error when someone wants to register their last name as "O'Reilly"? The user is well-intentioned, but your site breaks when they use their real name.

That's reason enough to detect and fix cases of SQL injection in your code.

You didn't post your code that builds the SQL query from this input, so what you have shown is only circumstantial evidence. But I do infer that you are copying a GET input into your SQL query without proper escaping or the preferred method, using a query parameter.